# how to clone or duplicate fields with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this markup

```
<div class="input text">
   <label for="Experience0ExperienceContent">Experience Content</label>
   <input name="data[Experience][0][experience_content]" class="span3" id="Experience0ExperienceContent" type="text">
</div>
```

It's possible to clone or duplicate it incrementing the 0 value every time the user make click on a link? I mean all the 0 when user clicks one time the link need to go to 1 then if click again need to go to 2 and so on and of course maintaining the same markup every time, any advice or help?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Storing data in a "name" attribute implies that you might be doing it wrong.  I'd look at storing the data elsewhere -- maybe a "data" attribute or something.

Comment: I'm not storing nothing in name is just the name assigned to the field and it's called data[Experience][0][experience_content] ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try a little something like this:​

```
$("a").click(function() {        
    $("div.input.text")
        .last()
        .clone()
        .appendTo($("body"))
        .find("input").attr("name",function(i,oldVal) {
            return oldVal.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(_,m){
                return "[" + (+m + 1) + "]";
            });
        });        
    return false;        
});
```

As demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Xg4S/

Essentially on click of your anchor it will clone the last div and append it to the body (at least my example appends to the body - obviously you could append it to something more specific or `.insertAfter()` the last one), then take the number from the middle of the name and increment it via a regex replace.

Having done that though I'd like to note that you don't need to give your inputs unique names: all of the server-side technologies that I'd care to use can deal with multiple request parameters with the same name (e.g., Java has `getParameterValues()` that returns an array).

**EDIT:** Here's a version that clones only the input element, specifically the last input in the div, updates its id, and appends it to the end of the div. As per your comment this no longer changes the name (though obviously you can just throw in an additional `.attr()` call as above if you want to change the name too). Oh, and also this sets the value to blank (I forgot to do that above).

```
$("#extra a").click(function() {   
    var $div = $(this).next();
    $div.find("input")
        .last()
        .clone()
        .appendTo($div.append("<br/>"))
        .val("")
        .attr("id",function(i,oldVal) {
            return oldVal.replace(/\d+/,function(m){
                return (+m + 1);
            });
        });
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Xg4S/4/

Comment: Ok, this work fine as jsfiddle show but how I can only clone the input field and not all? also I want to show the new input below the clone before is this possible? Sorry for my ignorance but I'm not so good with jQuery :(

Comment: Also I not need to change name as you said but ID need to be changed and I try changing name by id in the function you leave here and is not working

Comment: @ReynierPM replace `appendTo($("body"))` with `insertAfter("div.input.text:last")`

Comment: You want to clone only the input? What about the label? If you put the input _inside_ the label you don't need the id attribute at all: `<label>Experience Content<input .../></label>`. Can you please update your question to give an "after" sample so that your desired result is 100% clear? _"I want to show the new input below the clone before"_ - I don't understand this; did you mean "below the cloned input"?

Comment: No I don't need to clone all not the div not the label just clone the input element and of course incrementing the ID value any time, as the code is now all the div is clone and I don't want this, what modifications I should be done to achieve this?

Comment: Ok, it's almost done but still having some issues. First I add "after("<br/>")" to insert a break at every cloned input so they appear below each and not beside, now it looks like $div.find("input").last().clone().appendTo($div).after("<br/>").val("").attr("id",function(i,oldVal) but the first element always appear beside and not below, why? The second problem is that I have several DIV with the same classes and then every time I click in the link to clone those related to the first one then it's cloned but in every place with div with class input, text appear.

Comment: Ok, don't worry I fix by myself :) the function is here: http://pastebin.com/gUYm9Xnv and many thanks for your support and the points goes to you as this is the best answer

Comment: I have another question, I have another INPUT that need to be clone in other link click I need to repeat the function or it can be parametrized and just past the link ID and also the DIV Id where the inputs that I want to clone reside?

Comment: I've edited my edit (and updated my demo) to use `$(this).next()` to get the div that follows whichever anchor was clicked. That way the same function will automatically cover all of the add functionality for all of the links within your "#extra" div.

Comment: Man you rocks but it's not working I click on any link and nothing happens :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, give it an id for better selector performance, I'll assume it `foo` for the link, `bar` for the field:

```
function buildId(id) {
  return 'data[Experience][' + id + '][experience_content]';
}

jQuery('#foo').click((function () {
  var i = 0;
  return function () {
    var $bar = jQuery('#bar');
    $bar
      .clone()
      .attr('id', buildId(i++))
      .insertAfter($bar);
  };
})());
```

Check the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) for the methods used.

Comment: Ok, this work but not in the right way at all so I made some modifications in order to get what I want and the function is this one: http://pastebin.com/yHX3PtRp because I want to clone just the input field but incrementing id and name values by one (i++) but it's not working, just clone the first time and values aren't incremented I miss something? What is wrong?

Comment: @ReynierPM check http://pastebin.com/GTvXV7br It will clone the `i`th element into another with id `i + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery clone() method and then retrieve the actual element's name, and then update the new elements name. Read [here](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for more

Heres an example

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Single page template</title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head> 


<body> 
<a href="#" id="cloneme" name="cloneme">Clone Me</a>
<div class="input text">
   <label for="Experience0ExperienceContent">Experience Content</label>
   <input name="data[Experience][0][experience_content]" class="span3" id="Experience0ExperienceContent" type="text">
    <input type="hidden" id="currentval" name="currentval" value="0" />

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
            var currentval = parseInt($("#currentval").val()) + 1;
            var cloneme = $("#Experience0ExperienceContent").clone();
            var newid = "Experience" + currentval + "ExperienceContent";
            cloneme.attr("id",newid);
           $("#currentval").val(currentval);
            $("div").append(cloneme);
        });
    })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

Here is the link to code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kYwXX/1/

Comment: where is the link to document ? Read here for more

Comment: Yes I knew that but the problem is I don't know how to build the selection because as you notice the HTML markup have this <div class="input text"> so when I clone the HTML once and once then how jQuery knows which of <div class="input text"> to select?

Comment: I included an example of cloning the input text. When you clone, I am incrementing a hidden input value which is initially set to zero. So based on that, I am able to update the cloned element Id.

Comment: @Reynier, yes the above code is cloning the input element, and it updated the 'id' attribute of the new element. Open your chrome developer tools, and see the change while you clone.

Comment: @DG3, nop it not works for me, see the image at this URL for results http://www.dropmocks.com/mBgo4I notice in Firebug NaN :(

Comment: can you try it now. Looks like the hidden input was not getting updated.

Comment: Still not working the hidden input as you said is not updated ah by the way the function now is this one: http://pastebin.com/Qah9AfyM please update your post and use this instead the old one and sorry for that :(

Comment: I moved the code into jsfiddle and edited my post to include the link to it. I put an alert after cloning. You can see the id of each element being changed.

Comment: Ok, you right it works but now I have a big problem because even if the name for all the inputs are the same to my PHP only the first one is arriving, did you know why?

Comment: can you show the code how you are sending data to php? If the name is same for all the inputs, the values are sent separated by commas.

Comment: Well I'm using CakePHP but I think this is not the problem. The HTML generated by Cake is here: http://pastebin.com/P16cpT2H (I remove some code to make it pretty and readable) and in the PHP file I just write debug($this->request->data); die(); nothing else