# how to add dinamically input fields and subfields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js

I need to add input fields dynamically so that you can, for all the fields that have been added, to add a new subdfield and to which you can also add a  new subfield. There are three levels of fields.

The below image represents the scheme fields. Does anyone give me advice on how to make this form and on usuable way send this form to the base?

[image: scheme of fields]

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441289/how-to-clone-or-duplicate-fields-with-jquery might help

Comment: Thanks I'll try combining this with the function to add input fields

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood the question you are basically looking for 
an easy way to generate dynamic html.

No matter if it is an input file or any other HTML tag, you can solve this 
via simple code.

You tagged the question with node.js so here is a simple way to generate dynamic html via Express ([Express](http://expressjs.com) is a Node web server).

```
router.get('/myRoute', function (req, res, next) {
    const HTML = '<input type="text">';
    res.end(HTML);
});
```

There are more advanced and reusable ways to do this but I think 
you should at first learn the basics.

You tagged the question also with php, just dive into this: [Using DOMDocument to create elements in an HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482826/using-domdocument-to-create-elements-in-an-html-file)