# Submitting dynamic table data via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a dynamic table, with an option to add/delete rows. For adding and deleting, I used a cloning function. The inputs associated with the table have a name like: name[0],name[1],name[2],etc.

To better understand my naming convention, the fiddle might come in handy: https://jsfiddle.net/tareenmj/amojyjjn/7/

When I attempt to use `form.serializeArray()` or even `form.serialize`, instead of giving me those names it gives me inputs with the same name (i.e. courseTB1[] for multiple values instead of courseTB1[0], courseTB1[1], etc). However when I use my ajax function when I submit the form, it works as expected. The problem is I can't submit my form.

Is there anyway to pass my form inputs via ajax in a JSON format which will adequately take care of names?

My jQuery code is as follows:

```
var formData=JSON.stringify($('#form').serializeArray());
var arr = {inputs: formData, nextTab:relatedTabID, currentTab: tabID};
alert(JSON.stringify(arr)); 
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'roa',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {inputs: formData, nextTab: relatedTabID, currentTab: tabID}, 
   success: function (data) {
        //if no error from backend validation is thrown
        $('#tabShow').html(data);
        checkboxFunction();
        if (relatedTabID === 'section6') {
           section6();
        }
       //else present the same form
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
});
```

Since I am a beginner at Jquery Ajax, this was my best shot at the function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: might be easier not to use json and use `serialize()` to send form encoded data ... the same as a regular form does with no ajax  using default browser submit process

Comment: your input element has the wrong format of name `<input type="text" name="sectionTB1[]" id="section" placeholder="Section" class="form-control">`

Comment: Yea I tried serialize() as well as serializeArray() and both don't have the proper naming convention.

Comment: you need to manually update the name like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441289/how-to-clone-or-duplicate-fields-with-jquery

Comment: please make sure your `form` has ID `#form` because in fiddle it's not there

Comment: @AgamBanga the naming convention takes care of the cloning bit tho? If I give it a name like xyz[], it will automatically increment the array upon a cloning request.

Comment: @Curiousdev yea sorry about that, in my original HTML code, it has an ID. Thanks for the heads up.